# downforeveryoneorjustme.com ? Yep, Just me! but how to fix?

Tags: server, connection-timeout

There's a tonne of websites out their which tell you if a websites down or whether its "just you". All of them say its me but don't tell me how to fix it.

I've tried everything that I can think of at my end to try and fix it.

Steps I've taken.

- Clear cookies
- Clear cache
- Changing browser
- Restarting device.
- Test on Different Device
- What next ?

Is there more I can do?? or is the site just blocking me?
The site is [codepen.io](http://codepen.io) which I have been using without any problems all day but now it just get “Connection Timeout”

#### Could someone produce a list of steps that someone should take to solve/determine the problem?

Comment: Try from a different computer and from a different wifi (you can use your phone 4G/3G) in order to eliminate the options.

Comment: yep tested on different devices. Didnt test on 4G/3G as the site is up for others so i have no reason to believe this wouldn't work.

Comment: just found this  http://laptapos.com/internet/how-to-fix-connection-timeout-error-on-google-chrome/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know what error you're getting from your browser(s).

Generally I'd recommend pinging the server in question from the command line, but codepen.io doesn't seem to respond to pings even though I can reach the website.

One possible problem is domain name resolution: at the moment codepen.io resolves to 54.191.194.10 or 52.11.18.29 so if you can reach the site at http://54.191.194.10 you probably have a name resolution issue.  This is sometimes caused by corporate IT or sh!tty service providers like comcast.  One of the better solutions is to change your network settings to use Google's public DNS https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

If you need to compare your own DNS lookup with what it should look like, you can use this site http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php and enter Google's 8.8.8.8 as the server address.

Comment: great thank, this is definitely the next step I was looking for.